# How to undo or set back to default chmod -R 755?

Tags: permissions, chmod, wordpress, chown

What I was trying to do is installing "wordpress" in my localhost on (ubuntu 14.04) i.e my path for localhost is " home/deepak/php "

Now what i did is this in terminal:

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /home/deepak/php/
sudo chmod -R 755 /home/deepak/php/
```

And now I can't create any folder or file in `/home/deepak/php/`

**PLEASE NOTE**:All I want now is to undo and set back to earlier as it was, both of above the command 1 & command 2, I don't care any wordpress for now. just help me in undoing those 2 commands.

Comment: just chown again to your username.  `sudo chown -R username:username /home/deepak/php/`

Comment: @Maythux actually, don't bother. The OP has crossposted this on U&L and there's already an answer there. Let's just close this one.

Comment: That's it?                                                       my username is deep. that means sudo chown -R deep:deep /home/deepak/php   will do?

Comment: yeah y not your are not suffering because of that right?

Comment: @deepakyadav cross-posting is [not allowed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068/203101) on the Stack Exchange network. It leads to duplicated effort which is precisely what just happened here. Please choose _one_ site and only ask there. So, please accept one of the answers, either here or on U&L and then delete your other question.

Comment: so how do i delete question on other site. this site is more relevant to me.

Comment: @deepakyadav You are welcome, if it helps you then consider to mark as answer. take a look to http://askubuntu.com/tour

Comment: @deepakyadav I'll close the other one then. Please don't do this again, as you see it leads to complications. I voted to close this one since your other Q already had an answer. If you prefer to keep this one, I will close the other.

Comment: @terdon ok, close the other one i'm only on askubuntu, i landed up there unknowingly. thanks for your help to.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

All of what you have is just change ownership  of that directory back to your user.

```
sudo chown -R username:username /home/deepak/php/
```

So in your caser username=deep

```
sudo chown -R deep:deep /home/deepak/php/
```

And for the command2

```
sudo chmod -R 755 /home/deepak/php/
```

this permission will be just fine for your now, but you probably change some permissions later if you face some problems